# Angular Smart Table drag headers with different td elements

Tags: angularjs, datatable, drag-and-drop, smart-table

I am using Angular Smart Table plugin for datatable. I am using [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/DRagFo?p=preview) plnkr
for drag headers feature. I tried it , it works fine but problem is that I have different td elements for example like checkboxes , radio etc .

for example in its code

```
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
    <td ng-repeat="col in columns">{{row[col]}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Here all elements of td are similar is I want like different elements I cannot use ng-repeat .

Here is mine one

```
<tr ng-repeat="t in displayedCollection">
            <td>{{t.Id}}</td>
            <td>{{t.Title}}</td>
            <td>{{t.Content}}</td>
            <td>{{t.Status}}</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="t.IsActive" disabled="disabled"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="t.IsCommentAllowed" disabled="disabled"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="t.IsRatingAllowed" disabled="disabled"></td>
        </tr>
```

In this code headers are dragging but its columns are not. This code is using [lrDragNDrop](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/lrDragNDrop) plugin for drag n drop . What should I do is it possible Need help?

Comment: Can you post a plnkr with the none working example?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/2MY6thXpgZ2vxC2cauvY?p=preview  
here it is u can drag headers but whole column not dragging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5ilUmxM0yCP9TZ2TwEOp?p=preview) that works ...

The idea is to add the "other" types of columns to the columns list and then use ng-if. Hope that works for you.

**Markup**

```
 <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
   <td ng-repeat="col in columns">
     <span ng-if="col != 'cb'">{{row[col]}}</span>
     <span ng-if="col == 'cb'">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.IsActive">
     </span>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.columns=['cb', 'firstName', 'lastName','age','email','balance'];
```

** **UPDATED (using ng-switch instead of ng-if)**

```
      <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
          <td ng-repeat="col in columns" ng-switch="col">
            <span ng-switch-default>{{row[col]}}</span>
            <span ng-switch-when="cb">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.IsActive">
            </span>
          </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: Ok Got the idea just use nf-if to check columns name that match the condition

Comment: @Ghazanfar : yea, ng-switch would be better ... I'll update the answer.